# it is not found about test controller requestMapping

Tags: java, request-mapping

I'm setting up a new server, and want to test controller, so I create a 'superadmin' class, but when it run on server I acquire a error 404.

The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. I do not know where I was wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Running MySQL, tomact v8.5, I have done the JUnit test for AreaDao and AreaService,and these two tests have succeeded, just have an error with test controller.

*AreaController.java*

```
package com.zykj.testOne.web.superadmi;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/superadmin")
public class AreaController {
    @Autowired
    private AreaServices areaServices;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listarea", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    private Map<String, Object> listArea() {
        Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Area> list = new ArrayList<Area>();
        try {
            list = areaServices.getAreaList();
            modelMap.put("rows", list);
            modelMap.put("total", list.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            modelMap.put("success", false);
            modelMap.put("errMsg", e.toString());
        }
        return modelMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell the exact endpoint url that you're trying to access? Also how have you deployed the application on tomcat?

Comment: can you also put your what is the test that you wrote for the controller ?

Comment: Also thanks for Mr.Garg. I want test my controller if it works properly. I used ‘@requestMapping’. All my processes are based on a teaching video. And  all the previous steps are correct. So I think my configuration is right. Thank you again sincerely.

Comment: Sorry.I can not reply to your comment directly. so I answer here one by one. First answer Mr.Bhat's question. My access url = localhost:8080/testOne/superadmin/listarea; Second, my web application could run normally on tomact, it can normal assess the index.jsp,(Display, Hello world). Just when I had a test for 'superadmin' with '@requestMapping', I can not access that url which I showed.Thanks for your time.